# How can I calculate final gear ratio when the drive train contains multiple gears with some reductions on the same shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to calculate some rather long and complex drive trains, this is a project that I have worked up to, but its the first  problem of its kind I have come across, to try and explain the position I am in please follow my example of how I am trying to calculate the final ratios and if I am going wrong, please can you point out where I have gone wrong and if you have the time, why.

Example:
In the image below is a simple drive train, it consists of three shafts with four gears turning.( I know it doesn't look it, but please assume all teeth are of the correct size and mesh with no problems)

- Shaft 1
- - Input Gear 1 (Purple) has 24 teeth
- Shaft 2
- - Driven 2 (Red) has 12 teeth
- - Driven 3 (Blue) has 15 teeth
- Shaft 3
- - Output Gear(Green) has 10 teeth.

So the power travels through Purple,Red, Blue Green.

Now for my Math.

though a 2:1 is connected to a 3:2 I have been calculating  the ratio like this, but I am sometimes getting different answers with long (up 12 gears) trains in my project.

I would calculate the final ratio like this:

(12/24)x(15/12)x(10/15) = 0.416(RECUR.)

This is where I am going wrong
Is the Final ratio 100:416 (1:0.416)
or is it 
 1/0.416 = 1.666 = ~16:10  or is it something else?
[image: Image shows example drive train as described in the example above]

Any help is greatly appreciated, im stuck at the moment and need to get on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Woodgears](https://woodgears.ca/gear/ratio.html) web site, one takes the gear ratios independently and "adds them together" as shown in the video within the linked site.

In your example, the progression is as follows:

24:12, 15:10 which reduces to 2:1 and 3:2

Two (first ratio) times one and one-half (second ratio) is 3, which provides for a 3:1 increase or a 1:3 reduction if the reverse is created. There is no math between the red and blue gears as one rotation of the red is one rotation of the blue.

Comment: Thank you, this is the issue that I had, several of the gear trains have fixed gears on the shaft similar to the Red/Blue gears and it is this that i am trying to find out.  Many Thanks, i would give it a +1 but for some reason rep doesn't translate from one exchange to another, and I seem to lose it when i come back after a few weeks...

Comment: So "adds them together" really means "*Multiply* them together"?

Comment: Yes, I realize now that the terminology is poorly phrased for this operation.